# Django: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden) (fix the error please)

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, django, django-rest-framework

I successfully registered from React app(front-end) and saved the **key** (Got from server) in local storage.

here is my code:

```
    signupHandler=()=>{
        fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/rest-auth/registration/', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers:{
                'content-type':'application/json',
            },
            body:JSON.stringify({
                'username':this.state.username,
                'email': this.state.email,
                'password1': this.state.pass1,
                'password2': this.state.pass2
            })
        })
        .then((response)=>{
            response.json().then((result)=>{
                if (result.key !== undefined){
                    localStorage.setItem('login', JSON.stringify({login: true,token:result.key}))
                    this.setState({registered: true})
                }
            })
        })
    }
```

I made a method , which will do `this.setState({addedToCart: true})`, if the result = 'response':'ok'.

here is the method:

```
    addToCart=()=>{
        var id = this.props.id
        let store = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('login'))
        console.log(store.token);//successfully print the key
        var url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/addToCart/'+id+'/'
        fetch(url,{
            method:'GET',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Authorization': 'Token '+store.token
            }
        }).then(res=>res.json().then(result=>{
            if(result.response === 'ok'){
                this.props.dispatch({
                    type: 'itemInCart',
                })
                this.setState({addedToCart: true})
            }
        }))
    }
```

and in Django(views.py):

```
@api_view(['GET'])
@permission_classes((IsAuthenticated,))
def addToCart(request, pk):
    product = get_object_or_404(Product, pk=pk)
    mycart, __ = Cart.objects.get_or_create(user=request.user)
    mycart.product.add(product)

    return Response({'response':'ok'})
```

but it shows >>>`the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)`

I know Django is saying I'm un-authenticated.
but why i'm un-authenticated? (where i send the token/key to the server).

so, How can I get the **response:ok**? how can i make me authenticated?

Comment: Not sure what the exact issue is, but the [docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/) contain this example line: `@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])`

Answer (score 0):

Actually the un-authenticated status is 401, status 403 is when you are authenticated, but the current user is not authorized to access to the requested resource. You must check the permissions your user have in the Django API, if you have some middleware to check for role based permissions or if the addToCart is restricted to certain roles.